# jQuery Append in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a jQuery code that deals with a JSON feed and generate some HTML code that I append to a specific div in my wordpress website. This works just fine in all browsers except in Opera, it gives nothing at all. Here is the fiddle of my code http://fiddle.jshell.net/7amama/NErEG/1/

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here, not just in the fiddle? I don't see any calls to jQuery `append()` in the fiddle.

Comment: @hamama have you checked console output for errors? I can't see any difference in fiddle between Chrome and Opera 12.15

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the append I meant, I was using .html instead. With the alerts loading in the first fiddle, I was testing if my jQuery is really generating the html code or not.. it doesn't work in Opera http://fiddle.jshell.net/7amama/NErEG/3/

Comment: Your fiddle looks the same for me in Chrome, Firefix, and Opera.

Comment: when I use it in fiddle, it works fine.. But in my project, it doesn't work in Opera!

Comment: even the simplest append doesn't work on Opera I dun know why:
$('#videos').append("Videos Title");

Answer (score 0):

I just moved my jQuery scripts inside their tags (I mean I put the code that append html code into `#videos` div inside the div itself in the body).
I don't know why, but it really worked just fine; any clues what might have been the reason?